# Angular 7 - To change background div using radio button

Tags: angular, background, radio-button

This is the html code (home.component.html):

```
<form #fNews="ngForm">
<app-news *ngFor="let data of contentNews" [data]="data"></app-news>
</form>
```

This is the ts code (home.component.ts)

```
this.contentNews = [  
   {  
      "idcontentnew":1,
      "title":"Productos"
   },
   {  
      "idcontentnew":2,
      "title":"Servicios"
   }
];
```

This is the html code (news.component.html)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xl-12 col-sm-12" [ngClass]="{'divSelected': data.idcontentnew == idSelected}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="radio" id="inputIdNew{{data.idcontentnew}}" name="inputIdNew" (click)="selected(data.idcontentnew);" [(ngModel)]="inputIdNew" [value]="data.idcontentnew" /> <label for="id">Select new</label>
        </div>                
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="inputTitle{{data.idcontentnew}}" name="inputTitle{{data.idcontentnew}}" type="text" value="{{data.title}}" />
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

This is the code ts (news.component.ts)

```
@Input("data") data: any;

idSelected: any;

constructor() {
this.idSelected = null;
}

selected(idSelected: number) {
this.idSelected = idSelected;
}
```

My problem is that I need only to mark and change the background of the selected div. Now, if I select all the radio buttons, the background of all the divs will be changed.

If I did it with ngFor directly in the home component, it would work fine, but I want to do the news secction in a separate component.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be happening because idSelected variable is getting attached as true with each div of home.component.html *ngFor

Try applying *ngFor in news.component.html instead of home.component.html and also define contentNews variable in news.component.ts

Comment: Sorry, I got confused when I created the question, I had it with the same name, but it still does not work

Comment: Hey @Eladerezador I updated my answer which may solve your stated issue.